# Is there any flaw in the proof of $-1 = 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, fake-proofs

We have $i^2 = -1$ where $i = \sqrt{-1}$.
Now consider $$\sqrt{-1}\cdot \sqrt{-1}
             = \sqrt{(-1)\cdot(-1)}
             =  \sqrt1 = 1$$
Which proves $-1 = 1$.
Is there anything wrong with the above manipulation?

Comment: $\surd a \surd b = \surd ab$ is valid only if $a,b\geq 0$

Comment: No flaw, you've just shown in a few steps that mathematics is nonsense.

Comment: I like your comment Thomas.... :P

Comment: Since $-1$ is obviously not equal to $1$, the question isn't "**Is** there a flaw", but rather "**Where** is the flaw"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Nice comment, but you failed to take Poe's law into consideration...

Answer (score 4):

The equality $\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ doesn't hold for $a,b<0$

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the radical properties like you have done in a passage. The product of the square root of $-1$ is not the square root of the product!